# TextView Behavior issue (Swift)

Tags: swift, textview, format, line, newline

Been going mad for days trying to fix this problem.

** Everytime a new line is created the textView jumps up.**

Inserting another character, after the line is created, adjusts the textView correctly to its frame.

So the issue is only when a new line is created.

It's a minor issue but its quite irritating.

```html
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        print("text view did change\n")
        
        let fieldStatus = textView.text
  
        
        let textViewFixedWidth: CGFloat = self.textView.frame.size.width
        let newSize: CGSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textViewFixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
        var newFrame: CGRect = self.textView.frame
        
        var textViewYPosition = self.textView.frame.origin.y
        var heightDifference = self.textView.frame.height - newSize.height
        
       
        self.textView.frame = newFrame

        
        self.textView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.UserMessageView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.UserMessageView.frame.height.floatingPointClass
        
        UserMessageViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height + 8
        
        
        if UserMessageViewHeightConstraint.constant >= 250 {
            
            println("stop growing")
            let stopGrowth: CGFloat = self.UserMessageView.frame.height
            
            let currentHeight = self.textView.frame.height
            
           UserMessageViewHeightConstraint.constant = stopGrowth
        
        }
        
        if countElements(fieldStatus) >= 500 {
            textView.deleteBackward()
        }
        
        println("\(countElements(fieldStatus))")


    }
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

/Will

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in textViewDidChange() method?

Comment: @abdullah I'm trying to make the textView behave normal to a textview in a chat application.

Comment: I just realized, perhaps I should put the code in different method or function? Would that fix the problem?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance about textview in chat application, but I would like to the behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Everytime a new line is created, I want the textview to keep the next line at a fixed distance from the keyboard